# Why does Openbox on Gnome give me an empty desktop?

Tags: gdm, openbox

I installed new 12.04 and Openbox. I logged in with GNOME/Openbox and now after system starts I see only Desktop background image and nothing more. When I right click I can do normal GNOME actions like create folder and nothing more really. alt+f2 doesn't start run window though I managed to create a folder and then with Nautilus start terminal but I really don't know what to do next. Two questions:

1. Why doesn't Openbox start properly?
2. How in this situation I can get back to GDM login screen and choose other option to log in?

Comment: Openbox **did** start properly. It's just that Openbox is a Window Manager, not a full DE like most people are accustomed to. If I remember correctly, there is an action to exit Openbox that one can add to a key bind in the `-rc.xml` file. Quick edit: Here it is: http://openbox.org/wiki/Help:Actions#Exit

Answer (score 1):

you may need "openbox-xdgmenu" package to have a minimal (and updateable) right click menu, at least with "exit" command.

Answer (score 0):

1.
Unable to give an exact reason why the Openbox/Gnome session doesn't work correctly. I tried installing package "openbox-xdgmenu" which didn't help. I also have the same problem as described in the OP.
Perhaps select the straight "Openbox" session when logging in.

2.
Use the `Ctrl-Alt-F1` key combination to get a console then run
`sudo service gdm restart` (at the moment I don't have gdm installed so not 100% sure if command is correct, tab completion should help when typing it)

Comment: This doesn't provide an answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

The <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> key shortcut will open the `tty1` console. While in console execute the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install openbox-xdgmenu
sudo service gdm restart
sudo reboot
```